# How to add onclientclick to a control that is dynamically created in the codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick

I have a `checkbox` that is dynamically created in the code-behind. I also need add a `textbox`, that is visible if the `checkbox` is checked. I know I can use

`checkBox.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return func();")`.

But my question is how do I write the `func()` since my `textbox` is also created dynamically in the code-behind?

Update: Thanks for the answer. But if there any way not using JQuery? Also, my checkbox id is dynamically created in the code-behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by passing the id of the `text box` as follows

```
TextBox tx=new TextBox();
tx.Id="abc";
checkBox.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return func('"+checkBox.ClientId+"','"+tx.ClientId+"');");
```

and you can get the id in your java-script function.

```
function fun(checkboxId,textboxId)
{
    var remember= document.getElementById('checkboxId');
    if (remember.checked){
        document.getElementById(textboxId).disabled="disabled";
    }
    else{
         document.getElementById(textboxId).disabled="";
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this if helps you..I have used jquery

```
            $('.lettertyp').attr('checked', false);
            // Check current checkbox
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
            // Find the Sibling of the TextBox and SHow it
            $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]').show();
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/fNtzT/18/)